# failureFlash doesn't showing flash message

Tags: node.js, passport.js, ejs, passport-local

***When I open my login page and provide my credentials and then successRedirect reflects on another page and even if i provide wrong credentials then it also redirect different page. but the main problem is why failureFlash doesn't showing any message. and I am using ejs template and passport js local strategy.***

```
app.js

const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const session = require('express-session')
const expressValidator = require('express-validator')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
const path = require('path')
const passport = require('passport')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const routes = require('./routes/index')
const errorHandlers = require('./handlers/errorHandlers')
require('./handlers/passport')

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'))
//app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')



app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(expressValidator());

// populates req.cookies with any cookies that came along with the request
//app.use(cookieParser());


app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  key: process.env.KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.msg = req.flash();
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  res.locals.currentPath = req.path;
  next();
}); 



// After allllll that above middleware, we finally handle our own routes!
app.use('/', routes);


// If that above routes didnt work, we 404 them and forward to error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.notFound);

// One of our error handlers will see if these errors are just validation errors
app.use(errorHandlers.flashValidationErrors);

// Otherwise this was a really bad error we didn't expect! Shoot eh
//if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  /* Development Error Handler - Prints stack trace */
  //app.use(errorHandlers.developmentErrors);
//}

// production error handler
//app.use(errorHandlers.productionErrors);

// done! we export it so we can start the site in start.js
module.exports = app;
```

```
passport.js


const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

```
authController.js

const passport = require('passport');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');

exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/register',
  failureFlash: 'Invalid email or password',
  successRedirect: '/dash',
});

exports.forgot = async (req, res) => {
  // 1. See if a user with that email exists
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (!user) {
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }

console.log(user)
}

exports.logout = (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
 // req.flash('success', 'You are now logged out! ');
  res.redirect('/login');
};

exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  // first check if the user is authenticated
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next(); // carry on! They are logged in!
    return;
  }
  req.flash('error', 'Oops you must be logged in to do that!');
  res.redirect('dashhome');
};
```

```
register.ejs(and this my failureRedirect ejs file)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SignUp V4</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/imagesL/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendorL/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fontsL/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fontsL/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendorL/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendorL/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendorL/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendorL/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendorL/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cssL/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cssL/main.css">


<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>


    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('imagesL/bg-01.jpg');">
            <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-54">
                <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="/register" method="POST">
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-49">
                        Sign Up
                    </span>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">Who are You Representing?</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="user1" placeholder="Type Who You Are Representing?">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">Full Name</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Type Your Full Name">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">Company/Institution Name</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="user3" placeholder="Type Your Company/Institution Name">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">Company/Institution No.</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="user4" placeholder="Type Your Company/Institution No.">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">Current Address</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="user5" placeholder="Type Your Current Address">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">Company/Institution Current Address</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="user6" placeholder="Type Your Company/Institution Current Address">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">Active Phone No.</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="user7" placeholder="Type Your Active Phone No.">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>
                  <!--
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "Username is reauired">
                        <span class="label-input100">Company/Institution Phone No.</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="user8" placeholder="Type Your Company/Institution Phone No.">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>
                    -->

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">Active Email ID</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Type Your Active Email ID">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">Company/Institution Active Email ID</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="email" name="user10" placeholder="Type Your Company/Institution Active Email ID">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>


                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-49">
                        For KYC
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">Aadhar Number</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="number" name="user11" placeholder="Type Your Aadhar Number">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <span class="label-input100">PAN Number</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="string" name="user12" placeholder="Type Your PAN Number">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <input  type="checkbox" name="userTerm1">
                        <span name="userTerm11">I agree to the Terms of Use</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "required field is empty">
                        <input  type="checkbox" name="userTerm2" >
                        <span name="userTerm22">I agree to the Terms and Conditions</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                        <span class="label-input100">Password</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Type Your Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf190;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                        <span class="label-input100">Confirm Password</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Type Your Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf190;"></span>
                    </div>



                    <div class="text-right p-t-8 p-b-31">
                        <a href="#">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">
                                Sign Up
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="txt1 text-center p-t-54 p-b-20">
                        <span>
                            Or Sign Up Using
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-c-m">
                        <a href="#" class="login100-social-item bg1">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="login100-social-item bg2">
                            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="login100-social-item bg3">
                            <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>

<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="/vendorL/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="=/vendorL/animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="/vendorL/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendorL/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="/vendorL/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendorL/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="/vendorL/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="/jsL/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your ejs file?

Comment: yeah sure @dimitristseggenes

Comment: but which one ejs file successRedirect or failureRedirect file @dimitristseggenes

Comment: post the one you have the problem, just the piece of ejs code that display flash messages

Comment: this is file when i provide wrong credentials, then it reflect to this page but not showing any error @dimitristseggenes

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.js` file replace `res.locals.msg = req.flash();` with 
`res.locals.errorMsg = req.flash("error");`

And in your ejs file add this piece of code wherever you want to display it.

```
<% if (errorMsg) { %>
<p><%= errorMsg %></p>
<% } %>
```

If you want to display **success** flash messages, you add this 
`res.locals.successMsg = req.flash("success");` after `error` and you display them in the same way in your ejs file

```
<% if (successMsg) { %>
<p><%= successMsg %></p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: can you tell me when I add successFlash then I have to add same ejs code to that ejs file

Comment: yes it work but when I same ejs code paste into successRedirect ejs file then it doesn't show any successFlash message. please also tell me answer for the successFlash

Comment: if you want to display success messages you have to add the message in the `req.flash` object inside your controller. `req.flash('success', 'Successful!');`

Comment: if it solved your problem, you can accept the answer